# how to read current from sense pins of UWS-5/10-Q48 muRata chip with arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, current

I have a muRata UWS-5/10-Q48 DC-DC converter chip which has sense pins and I hope to read the current draw of the load which is connected to the arduino and print out the current draw.  I am not sure how to read the current using the sense pins.  Attached is the data sheet: http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/uws.pdf which refers to remote sensing around page 23.

Comment: In general, sense pins are connected to *sense resistors* that are << 1 Ohm (it depends on the expected current). You simply measure the voltage drop across these resistors and it will be proportional to the resistance (very precise known value). Therefore, V/R = I.

Comment: @sherrellbc: the sense pins on these Muurata supplies are for remote voltage sensing, not for current measurement.

Answer (score 2):

The sense pins on those supplies allow the voltage regulator to sense the voltage at the load, and so compensate for any voltage drop in the wires between the supply and load.

As stated in the datasheet, if you are not using the remote voltage sensing feature, the sense pins should be connected to the power supply output pins.

You cannot use the sense pins to measure the power supply output current.

Comment: how would I read the voltage then from the load into Arduino

Comment: Assuming that the load ground is connected to the Arduino ground, you simply connect the load positive terminal to an Arduino analog input, through a voltage divider if necessary.

Comment: @user3342460, make sure you are not setup to use the 12V output if that is what you intend to do.